# Instance variable still references after 'dup'

Tags: ruby, dup

I have an object of a class, and I want to duplicate it with `dup`. One of the instance variables is an array, and it seems to be referencing it. I thought dup actually created a DUPLICATE.

Here's my IRB session:

```
irb(main):094:0> class G
irb(main):095:1> attr_accessor :iv
irb(main):096:1> def initialize
irb(main):097:2> @iv = [1,2,3]
irb(main):098:2> end
irb(main):099:1> end
=> nil

irb(main):100:0> a=G.new
=> #<G:0x27331f8 @iv=[1, 2, 3]>

irb(main):101:0> b=a.dup
=> #<G:0x20e4730 @iv=[1, 2, 3]>

irb(main):103:0> b.iv<<4
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):104:0> a
=> #<G:0x27331f8 @iv=[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would expect `a` to be unchanged, because `dup` creates a whole new variable, not reference.

Also note that if you were to replace `[1,2,3]` with a scalar in `G::initialize`, `dup` will not reference it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dup` crates a shallow copy](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/dup); the objects referred to by instance variables are not copied.

The canonical (e.g., Really Easy) deep copy hack is to marshal/unmarshal, which may or may not work in your actual usecase (assuming this is a simplified example). If it doesn't, or if marshalling is to inefficient, the `initialize_copy` route is a better option.

```
pry(main)> a = G.new
=> #<G:0x9285628 @iv=[1, 2, 3]>
pry(main)> b = a.dup
=> #<G:0x92510a8 @iv=[1, 2, 3]>
pry(main)> a.iv.__id__
=> 76819210
pry(main)> b.iv.__id__
=> 76819210
pry(main)> b = Marshal::load(Marshal.dump(a))
=> #<G:0x9153c3c @iv=[1, 2, 3]>
pry(main)> a.__id__
=> 76819220
pry(main)> b.__id__
=> 76193310
```

Answer (score 7):

The default implementation of `dup` and `clone` just make a shallow copy, so you will have two objects referring to the same array.  To get the behavior that you want, you should define an `initialize_copy` function (which is called by `dup` and `clone`):

```
class G
  attr_accessor :iv
  def initialize_copy(source)
    super
    @iv = source.iv.dup
  end
end
```

Then the two objects will refer to two different arrays.  If the arrays have mutable objects in them, you might want to go even deeper and `dup` each object in the arrays:

```
def initialize_copy(source)
  super
  @iv = source.iv.collect &:dup
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `dup` or `clone` method:

```
  def dup
    Marshal::load(Marshal.dump(self))
  end
```